# Обновление формы

Tags: php, post, form

При обновлении формы данные отправляются повторно. Как можно этого избежать ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно делать редирект после отправки формы. 
Как вариант можно сделать это с помощью     `header("Location: <адрес переадресации>");`

Comment: а если оставатся на этой же странице ?

Comment: @Andrii Отправляйте на бакграунде через `ajax`

Comment: Если хочешь что бы страница не перезагружалась то тогда череза ajax если это не принципиально, то можешь делать перенаправление на эту же страницу.